# Make telebot mute new user for 24 hours

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I have this code

```
import time
from time import time
bot = telebot.TeleBot('<MY-BOT-TOKEN>')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=[
    "new_chat_members"
])
def mut(message):
    bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, USER_ID , until_date=time()+86400)
```

It listens for new users, and it has mute command, but how can i get their ID with TeleBot?

Comment: You've placed your **private BOT token** in the question. I removed it, but it's still visible in the history. Consider renewing the token at @botFather to prevent other people abusing it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def mut(message):
    bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, until_date=time()+86400)
```